# How do I make a new API in the Google Cloud Platform console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

In AWS, making a new API is as easy as going to the API Gateway service and clicking "Create API". How do I do the same in GCP? The Endpoints service does not appear to offer any way of creating an API.

Answer (score 0):

At GCP there are several offers to deploy APIs, and as you have pointed Cloud Endpoints do not offer to ways to create aPI, but it provides frameworks to to base on and to integrate with the actual application hosting offers (App Engine, Compute Engine GKE, Cloud Run, Cloud Functions).

I would follow this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/create_api) in order to create the base for your API and later [deploy and test your API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/test-deploy). Notice that in those tutorial App Engine is used to deploy your API.